# Why does Stanford NER tagger give different tags for similar lists?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition, pos-tagger

I would like to understand better why the Stanford NER (Name Entity Recognition) tagger yields different results for the same words, depending on the list of words you submit to it.

Here is an example:

```
from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger

user ="MYUSERPATH"

stpath = user + 'PATHTOSTANFORDTAGGER'
St = StanfordNERTagger(stpath + 'classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz', stpath+'stanford-ner.jar', encoding ='utf-8')

words1 = ["I","am", "amazed", "by", "Dylan","van", "Baarle", "and", "Remco", "Evenepoel"]
words2 = ["I","am", "amazed", "by","Dylan","van", "Baarle", "and","Remco", "Evenepoel", "Paris","Roubaix","is","a","great","race","I","watch","on","Eurosport"]
text_pars = St.tag(words1)
text_pars2 = St.tag(words2)
print(words1)
print(text_pars)
print(text_pars2)
```

Here the list `words2` is the concatenation of `words1` and a second piece of a sentence. When I compare the tags of these two sentences, I can see that the output for the same words is not the same.

Here is the output of `print(text_pars)`, which tagged `words1`. It accurately tagged "Remco" and "Evenepoel" and a PERSON.

```
[('I', 'O'), ('am', 'O'), ('amazed', 'O'), ('by', 'O'), ('Dylan', 'PERSON'), ('van', 'PERSON'), ('Baarle', 'PERSON'), ('and', 'O'), ('Remco', 'PERSON'), ('Evenepoel', 'PERSON')]
```

The output of the second instance yields different results. It now tags "Remco" and "Evenepoel" as 'ORGANIZATION':

```
[('I', 'O'), ('am', 'O'), ('amazed', 'O'), ('by', 'O'), ('Dylan', 'PERSON'), ('van', 'PERSON'), ('Baarle', 'PERSON'), ('and', 'O'), ('Remco', 'ORGANIZATION'), ('Evenepoel', 'ORGANIZATION'), ('Paris', 'ORGANIZATION'), ('Roubaix', 'ORGANIZATION'), ('is', 'O'), ('a', 'O'), ('great', 'O'), ('race', 'O'), ('I', 'O'), ('watch', 'O'), ('on', 'O'), ('Eurosport', 'LOCATION')]
```

Why are they different? Does it have to do with the surroundings of the words (Many words tagged as organization after it)?

Answer (score 1):

The tagger works by taking features of the surrounding words.  A city name late in a name is a tell that it is *probably* part of an Organization, for example (Paris Hilton non-withstanding).

As a human who knows nothing about these entities, this looks like a completely reasonable decision anyway.  Consider:

`"I", "am", "amazed", "by", "Dylan", "van", "Baarle", "and", "Remco", "Evenepoel"`

Okay, something ending with `van Baarle` is probably a person, and that context makes me think the second NE is also a person.

`words2 = ["I", "am", "amazed", "by", "Dylan", "van", "Baarle", "and", "Remco", "Evenepoel", "Paris", "Roubaix", "is", "a", "great", "race", "I", "watch", "on", "Eurosport"]`

I read this as you're just live streaming your consciousness and have two separate thoughts in mind:

- Dylan van Baarle amazes you
- You like watching a race named "Remco Evenepoel Paris Roubaix"